# How to remove special characters ^@ from a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How can i prevent the special characters i.e ^@ from being written to the file while writing the dataframe to s3?

Comment: You can remove those characters in the first place

Comment: like when reading the rdd.. but how can i replace it on all colums or entire file?

Comment: That is the `null` character in [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation).

Comment: Thanks @pault, but how can i replace it?

Answer (score 0):

using df.option("quote", "") while saving to file handled the ascii null character.